# how do you use the specific parameter _body in the nodejs bitbucket package?

Tags: node.js, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to utilize this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitbucket
I'm trying to do multiple things such as creating a repository and creating branches.
However, creating branches requires the _body parameter according to documentation:
https://bitbucketjs.netlify.app/#api-repositories-repositories_createBranch
The documentation DOES NOT specify a template for what the _body parameter should be.

I decided to experiment and I'm currently utilizing this as my _body:

```
let body = {
             "name" : branchName,
             "target" : {
                  "hash" : "default",
                }
           }
```

However, I'm currently getting errors.